# MongoDB Find query returning error, no idea why

Tags: mongodb, query

I am learning MongoDB by myself. I am following all the official guides as well as watching videos and I am practicing on a movie database. Each document has an array "crew" with a "give_name" (not given_name) property and an array "ratings" with a "rating_date" property. I want to query movies that starring Leonardo DiCaprio rated after 2010-01-01. The below line of code seems to be correct to me according to what I have seen, however, it returns an error

```
clone(t={}){const r=t.loc||{};return e({loc:new Position("line"in r?r.line:this.loc.line,"column"in r?r.column:...<omitted>...)} could not be cloned.
```

Could anyone show me where is the mistake? Because I have been staring at this string for a good couple of hours and made different changes so far unsuccesfully. Thank you.

```
db.movie.find({
  "$and": [
  {"crew": {"$elemMatch" {
    "give_name": "Leonardo DiCaprio"}}},
  {"ratings": {"$elemMatch": {
    "rating_date": {"$gte": ISODate("2010-01-01")}
  }}}]
},
{
  "_id": 0,
  "crew.give_name.$": 1,
  "ratings.rating_date.$": 1
})
```

Comment: You missed the colon: `{"crew": {"$elemMatch" {` must be `{"crew": {"$elemMatch": {` Maybe use a proper JavaScript editor like [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) - it is open-source!